# PayPal Permission API

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

Im building a store where merchants(sellers) can sale their goods to the customers. Im using PayPal Expresscheckout for the payments. I have tested with my own API credentials, and it works fine.

However, to be able to use the ExpressCheckout API's as a specific merchant, i have to get it's permissions.

Can they give me their permissions directly from their profile? 
I dont want to implement some special workflow for getting permissions from them.

Should i then store the credentials for each merchant in my own database?

What type of credentials is it? How/Where can merchant get these and send me ?

I have read some Permission API docs, but im not sure i have understood it really, yet. So would be glad to  get direct answer from someone who already have experiense with this.

Thank you!

Comment: by credentials what do you mean??

Comment: i mean the data i should have to be able to call expresscheckout api's as some merchant. for ex. when i tested with my own account, i used api_username, api_password and api_signature

Comment: then if you are using multiple merchants then you need to store in database but for only one. you can hard code this.

Comment: what you exactly mean by "but for only one?" .. merchants can register on my site, so i should be able to process payments for each of them ...

Comment: Okay. then for multiple merchants you need to store there credentials in database. thats a good practice.

Comment: and you will only need merchant's paypal id.

Answer (score 3):

They would need to either provide you with their API credentials from their account, or they would need to grant 3rd party permissions to your API username to be able to execute API calls on their accounts.